# Codeigniter 2.0: Upload various files with form inputs with different names

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, upload, codeigniter-2

I have a spent a few weeks with this issue, and have to ask you for help, I'm using Codeigniter 2.0, and load the `file_upload` library from autoload.php, but for some reason the files cannot be uploaded, and does not show any error when I do the `do_upload` function, here is a little code of a lot that I have (I have like 9  files input, only shown one on this example, for your comfort).

**View**

```
<?php
    $atributos = array(
        "id" => "form_anuncio",
        "name" => "form_anuncio"
    );
    echo form_open_multipart("usuarios/GrabarAnuncio",$atributos);
?>
<div class="form-group">

    <label for="logotipo">Logotipo
        <input type="file" name="logotipo" id="logotipo" placeholder="Logotipo" />
    </label>

    <?php if (($datos_usuario["Logotipo"] != NULL) ||  ($datos_usuario["Logotipo"] != "")) { ?>
        <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/logos/<?php echo $datos_usuario["idusuario"] . "_" . $datos_usuario["Logotipo"] ?>" alt="Logotipo Usuario" class="img-responsive" />
    <?php } ?>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" name="GuardarAnuncio" id="GuardarAnuncio" value="Guardar Anuncio" />
</div>

<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**Controller**

```
public function GrabarAnuncio()
{
    $this->load->model('Usuarios_model');
    $this->Usuarios_model->Grabar_anuncio();
    $this->miperfil();
}
```

**Model** (just an extract)

```
function Grabar_anuncio()
{
     /* Lot of code  */
        $directorio = './images/';
        $directorio1 = './images/logos/' . $ID . '/';
        if (!is_dir($directorio1)) {
            mkdir($directorio1, 0777, true);
        }
        $directorio2 = './images/fotos/' . $ID . '/';
        if (!is_dir($directorio2)) {
            mkdir($directorio2, 0777, true);
        }
        $directorio3 = './images/galerias/' . $ID . '/';
        if (!is_dir($directorio3)) {
            mkdir($directorio3, 0777, true);
        }

        if ($_FILES['logotipo']['name'] != "")
        {
            $config['upload_path'] = $directorio1;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '200';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';
            $config['overwrite'] = true;
            $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['logotipo']['name'];

            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('logotipo'))
            {
                //Never Enter Here
                $serverError = true;
                print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
                exit();
            }
        }
     /* More code  */
}
```

If you need any more detail you need just ask, I hope you can help me

UPDATE:

This is what i get when i do a var_dump before the upload

```
array (size=9)
  'logotipo' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'grinch1.png' (length=11)
      'type' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
      'tmp_name' => string 'G:\wamp\tmp\php5E16.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 58066
  'FotosLocalizacion1' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'anviz1.jpg' (length=10)
      'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => string 'G:\wamp\tmp\php5E46.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 219877
  'FotosLocalizacion2' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'anviz2.jpg' (length=10)
      'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => string 'G:\wamp\tmp\php5E47.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 172127
  'FotosLocalizacion3' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string 'anviz3.jpg' (length=10)
      'type' => string 'image/jpeg' (length=10)
      'tmp_name' => string 'G:\wamp\tmp\php5E57.tmp' (length=23)
      'error' => int 0
      'size' => int 136494
  'FotosLocalizacion4' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 4
      'size' => int 0
  'galeria1' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 4
      'size' => int 0
  'galeria2' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 4
      'size' => int 0
  'galeria3' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 4
      'size' => int 0
  'galeria4' => 
    array (size=5)
      'name' => string '' (length=0)
      'type' => string '' (length=0)
      'tmp_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'error' => int 4
      'size' => int 0
```

UPDATE 2

doing this after the if statement (outside of the bracket): die(var_dump($this->upload->data()));

```
array (size=14)
  'file_name' => string 'grinch1.png' (length=11)
  'file_type' => string 'image/png' (length=9)
  'file_path' => string 'G:/wamp/www/serviciosycomprasx/images/logos/127/' (length=48)
  'full_path' => string 'G:/wamp/www/serviciosycomprasx/images/logos/127/grinch1.png' (length=59)
  'raw_name' => string 'grinch1' (length=7)
  'orig_name' => string 'grinch1.png' (length=11)
  'client_name' => string 'grinch1.png' (length=11)
  'file_ext' => string '.png' (length=4)
  'file_size' => float 56.71
  'is_image' => boolean true
  'image_width' => int 280
  'image_height' => int 280
  'image_type' => string 'png' (length=3)
  'image_size_str' => string 'width="280" height="280"' (length=24)
```

Comment: You may need to use the for ($i=0; $i < ; $i++) in upload some how.

Comment: @mustang83 what do you mean? Do you have an example?

Comment: I would suggest using `die()` and `var_dump()` to debug what is happening before you get to the `do_upload`. For example, to make sure your `$directorio3` is exactly what its supposed to be you can go: `die(var_dump($directorio3));` and that would give you the value of the variable. If you do not see any output then that means you need to trace back to where your issue is.

Comment: I already tried that and double checked the directories creation, i think the error is  in this line "if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('logotipo'))", because i have a different name in my file input form that userfile i think @VincentWilkie

Comment: What happens if you go `die(var_dump($_FILES));` right before `if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('logotipo'))`?

Comment: Everything in your code here looks correct. The `if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('logotipo'))` statement will only be entered if the upload fails. What happens after the upload? Try doing this after the if statement (outside of the bracket): `die(var_dump($this->upload->data()));`

Comment: Update 2 on my question done with your advice, still does not upload the file to de directory @VincentWilkie

Comment: @VincentWilkie i don't know why , but adding $this->upload->data() uploaded the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
function Grabar_anuncio()
{
     /* Lot of code  */
        $directorio = './images/';
        $directorio1 = './images/logos/' . $ID . '/';
        if (!is_dir($directorio1)) {
            mkdir($directorio1, 0777, true);
        }
        $directorio2 = './images/fotos/' . $ID . '/';
        if (!is_dir($directorio2)) {
            mkdir($directorio2, 0777, true);
        }
        $directorio3 = './images/galerias/' . $ID . '/';
        if (!is_dir($directorio3)) {
            mkdir($directorio3, 0777, true);
        }

        if ($_FILES['logotipo']['name'] != "")
        {
            $config['upload_path'] = $directorio1;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '200';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';
            $config['overwrite'] = true;
            $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['logotipo']['name'];

            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('logotipo'))
            {
                //Never Enter Here
                $serverError = true;
                print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
                exit();
            }
        }
     /* More code  */
}
```

For this

```
function Grabar_anuncio()
{
     /* Lot of code  */
        $directorio = './images/';
        $directorio1 = './images/logos/' . $ID . '/';
        if (!is_dir($directorio1)) {
            mkdir($directorio1, 0777, true);
        }
        $directorio2 = './images/fotos/' . $ID . '/';
        if (!is_dir($directorio2)) {
            mkdir($directorio2, 0777, true);
        }
        $directorio3 = './images/galerias/' . $ID . '/';
        if (!is_dir($directorio3)) {
            mkdir($directorio3, 0777, true);
        }

        if ($_FILES['logotipo']['name'] != "")
        {
            $config['upload_path'] = $directorio1;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '200';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';
            $config['overwrite'] = true;
            $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['logotipo']['name'];

            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('logotipo'))
            {
                //Never Enter Here
                $serverError = true;
                print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
                exit();
            } else { 
                $this->upload->data();    
            }
        }
     /* More code  */
}
```